# Acceso a iframe dentro de iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Intento acceder a un iframe dentro de un iframe para acceder a un div determinado en un iframe, este es el código que uso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nosé acceder a ese "id" root.

Comment: La imágen de código no es una buena idea, [como crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), además en la imagen se ve un solo `iframe`

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
<iframe src="asdsad" id="chat-widget" onload="access()"></iframe>

<script>
function access() {
   var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
   var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
   console.log(innerDoc.body);
}
</script>
```

podrás ver su resultado en consola.